# React - Typescript problem with generic response type

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have Following typescript types:

```
export type Response<T> = { isSuccess: true; data: T } | { isSuccess: false; error: string };
```

and

```
export interface IItems {
    item1: IItemObject[]
    item2: IItemObject[]
}
```

Then in my react code I fetch data from api -->

Get result as the above "Response" type -->

And if isSuccess === true, response is stored into a state:

```
const [savedItems, setSavedItems] = useState<{number: number, items: Response<IItems>}[] | undefined>();
```

So my problem comes when trying to access the responses "data" object like this:

```
savedItems?.find((a: any) => a.number === inputNumber)?.items?.data?.item1
```

I get the following typescript error:

```
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Response<IItems>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type '{ isSuccess: false; error: string; }'.ts(2339)
```

I get the same error even when trying to use type guard like this:

```
const typeGuardTest = savedItems?.find((a: any) => a.number === inputNumber)?.items?.isSuccess
? (savedItems.find((a: any) => a.number === inputNumber)?.items.data?.item1)
: undefined;
```

Any idea where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Response` returns a union where only the success response has `data` property.

You need to check whether the `savedItems.items` is a success response:

```
if(savedItems.items.isSuccess) {
}
```

And if the `isSuccess` true then the typescript will be able to infer that `savedImages` is a success response and you'll be able to use `data`:

```
const response: { items: Response<IItems> } = {
  items: {
    isSuccess: true,
    data: { item1: [], item2: [] },
  },
};

if (response.items.isSuccess) {
  response.items.data.item1.find((v) => v);
}
```